# Link between the Windows Form and the Program.cs on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I come to ask for your help because i am a beginner on Visual Studio. I have a program.cs which consist to  program a microship. I want to create an application (Windows Form), to execute the program.cs to program the microship and have an interface to show me the progression. 
My question is, can i create a windows form separately and call the program to execute? so should i create a public class on the program.cs to be called?

I am stuck at the first step and it is frustrating..

If someone can guide me it will be very helpful! Thanks!

Abee / RF Test Engineer

Comment: Follow the tutorials to create your first WinForms application in Visual Studio, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/getting-started-with-windows-forms and then the link is obvious.

Comment: Thank you. But i already created the windows form, now i want to link the program to the form. For example, when i click on the button, it will run the program. Is it possible?

Comment: Then you'd better carefully edit the question to reveal your real question (with screen shots if possible). I assume you should first run the program and then click a button, not the other way around. So you see, your description is far from clear.